# Maven Dependency Conflict

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, project-management, pom.xml

A maven project consisting of some modules. One of my module is using guava dependency of google version `11.0.2`. Now i am integrating another module in my project which is also using guava but version `14`.

So i want that new module uses guava version `14` but remaining project use guava version `11.0.2`. I have tried adding `<exclusion></exclusion>` of guava to the new module but it didn't work.

Any tips to solve this.

Update: @Guillaume Darmont's Answer solves the problem for different modules. but now my problem is, the new modules has 2 dependency one of the them is using guava `11.0.2` and other is using `14.0`. how to manage this. can we specify separately in the pom of the module that which version of the guava it should use.?

Comment: I didn't fully understand your question. You are trying to use Guava `14` on both modules ? Also, do you use a common parent POM ?

Comment: i want to use guava 14 on the new module, which i am integrating. Older modules will be using guava 11.0.2 only. And yes i have a commmon parent POM.

Comment: Are you sure both 11.0.2 and 14 can coexist? In normal circumstances, only one of the libraries (appearing first in the classpath) will be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand your question, you may add a `<dependencyManagement>` for `guava` in your new module pom.xml :

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
          <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
          <version>14.0.1</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. it works for the situation mentioned. is it possible to use different version of dependency in single module. i mean the new module has 2 dependency one of them is using guava `11.0.2` and `14.0`. how to manage this.

Comment: No, it is not possible. All classes in a Maven module share the same classpath. BTW to simply your dependencies, you should only have one version of guava for all the modules of your project. Guava 14 should be mostly (if not totaly) backwards compatible with version 11.

Comment: maven-shade-plugin can be used to remap the packages in one artifact to another location, which would allow you to use one version that way and another version as normal.  However, that can greatly increase the size of your deployment (whether a fat JAR or all bundled individually), and tends to lead to outdated dependencies and potential issues if they are using a service loader or similar mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

`mvn dependency:tree` command will help to determine which module is bringing the Guava 14 jar file.

Comment: More specifically `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=com.google.guava` will display _just_ the parts of the dependency tree you're interested in, and include details about why a dependency was omitted (conflict/duplicate) in each case. [Apache Maven Project - Resolving conflicts using the dependency tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try `mvn dependency tree` and check the output it is possible that `11.0.2` has been transitively referenced from more than one of your projects dependencies and you will need to add exclusion to all the dependencies directly / indirectly pulling down the specific guava version you are trying to exclude.

Secondly resolving this conflict may not be straight forward. Looking at version number transition (11 to 14) sounds to me like a major transition, and you may have better chances keeping the 14 version and excluding the 11 something.

If the version change is not compatible with your application, you have pretty much no option but to use something like `OSGi` to ensure you can run different versions of same library in the project.

Comment: ... or maven shade plugin with package relocation